# How to modify Google Drive API key permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do you modify the permissions for an API key with Google?

I have an Google API key for accessing my files on Google Drive. I thought I had configured it with full permissions, but I recently found it's unable to delete files. Calling the `delete()` method from the Python API bindings results in the error:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/myfileuuid? returned "Insufficient permissions for this file". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient permissions for this file', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden', 'location': 'file.permissions', 'locationType': 'other'}]">
```

I've confirmed the file permissions are set so that everyone in my organization can do whatever they want with it. So the limiation must be the permissions with the key itself.

So I'm trying to find the page in Google admin for managing and editing your credentials and keys. However, I've been searching the Google admin, but I can't for the life of me find anything useful in it. A lot of it's been refactored since I created the key, and going to the "Keys and Credentials" page now redirects me to a new "Google Places" site that demands I sign up for a new monthly Maps account, which of course I don't want.

I need to give my key delete permission for my Google Drive account. Is that possible?

Edit: I think I finally found the app permissions edit page at https://admin.google.com/ac/owl/list/<app_uuid> located at "Security

> API Controls > App Access Control > myappname"

However, it says, "This app wants permission to access everything in your Google Drive. It will be able to do the same things you can do, including: .... Delete your files"

So my app already has permission to delete anything it wants on my Google Drive account in my organization. Why then is it being denied? I've confirmed it's using the correct key for the app.

The file I'm trying to delete was uploaded by another user, but they belong to my organization and the file's permission is open to everyone in my organization.

Is there some special permission that needs to be granted so the file can delete files uploaded by any user?